# mysql procedure for updating row

Tags: mysql

```
USE `sakila`;
DROP procedure IF EXISTS `change_user_name`;

DELIMITER $$
USE `sakila`$$
CREATE PROCEDURE `change_user_name` (actor_id int, first_name varchar(45), last_name varchar(45))
BEGIN

UPDATE actor SET first_name='first_name', last_name='last_name' WHERE actor_id='actor_id';


END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Why this procedure won't work, I don't receive any error message from mysql workbench

Comment: You have a premature DELIMITER in there,also you are using strings insted of input values and naming parameters the same as columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about the `DELIMITER` part, but to the function it should be something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `change_user_name` (actor_id_in int, first_name_in varchar(45), last_name_in varchar(45))
BEGIN

UPDATE actor
SET first_name=first_name_in,
    last_name=last_name_in 
WHERE actor_id=actor_id_in;
```

Note that when you specify text inside two quote 'example' it will see it as a string, not a column. You only have to use (back tic/double quotes/brackets not quotes) when dealing with columns/tables that have the name of a reserved word in your DBMS

Comment: @FAMO_php No problem, I'll appreciate an approval  then.

Comment: no problem, since I am relatively new in here how to do approval? Did I do it right way for your answer?

Comment: Yes you did @FAMO_php